# How to omit applying styles from certain class in CSS

Tags: html, css, sass, css-selectors

I am making a PR to one of OSS project but I stuck at thing where I want to perform following:

```html
<div class="vp-doc">
  <p>styled</p>
  <div class="vp-raw">
    <p>not styled</p>    
    <div>
      <p>not styled</p>    
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Let's say I have styles for all p tags placed inside `.vp-doc` but exclude if any ancestor has `.vp-raw` class.

I tried below but didn't worked:

```css
.vp-doc {
  :not(.vp-raw) {
    h1 {
      color: red;
    }    
  }
}
```

**NOTE: `p` elements can be nested deeper.**

Thanks to @fabrizio-calderan I was able to get closer but with `all: revert` it also removes the other styles as shown in snippet.

```css
p {
  font-weight: 600;
  color: green;
}

.vp-doc p {
  color: red;  
}

.vp-raw p {
  all: revert;
}
```

```html
<div class="vp-doc">
  <p>styled</p>
  <div class="vp-raw">
    <p>not styled</p>
    <div>
      <p>not styled</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Real-life scenario:

I am working on [VitePress](https://github.com/vuejs/vitepress) where it has vp-doc class which adds styling for markdown (h1, p, tags etc). However, When we use component for demo in docs component's  h1, p, etc tags also get styling. I opened an [issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vitepress/issues/199) in the repo and working on it. We decided to add `.vp-raw` class with shown structure to avoid adding styles by `vp-doc`. It's kind of isolation from `vp-doc` styles but other styles (added by component) should stay.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You could apply a style for `.vp-doc p` and revert all the properties for `.vp-raw p`

```css
.vp-doc {
  color: cornflowerBlue;
}

.vp-doc p { 
   color: yellowgreen; 
   font: 600 2rem system-ui; 
}

.vp-raw p { 
  /* resets the property to its inherited value 
     if it inherits from its parent or to the default 
     value established by the user agent's stylesheet */ 
  all: revert; 
}

/* or 
  .vp-doc .vp-raw * {
    all: revert; 
  }
*/
```

```html
<div class="vp-doc">
  <p>styled</p>
  <div class="vp-raw">
    <p>not styled</p>    
    <div>
      <p>not styled</p>    
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

in this example `revert` applies the initial `font-weight`, `font-size` and `font-family` but the `color` of the paragraph is inherited from its parent.

Comment: Oh great! I want to know, why I can't do `.vp-raw * { all: revert; }`. I don't know which tags will be there in `.vp-raw`

Comment: sure, `.vp-raw *` should work fine too, but you need to increase the specificity of this selector (e.g. `.vp-doc .vp-raw * { ... }`)

Comment: Moreover with `all: revert` if element have style like `p { color: tomato }` is ignored. How can I tackle it? Can't do something other than applying `all: revert`

Comment: you can revert every single property except the color, not just `all`

Comment: Sorry for unaccepting but this is also removing the styles other than those applied by `vp-doc`. Is there any other workaround that only removes `vp-doc` styles?

Comment: could you explain the real scenario in your question?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help. I have updated the question, please let me know if I add more context. Thanks :)